# Cpanel deployment of Django project getting 404 Not Found Error when entering any path besides just the domain

Tags: django, deployment, django-views, cpanel, django-urls

For the sake of the question, the domain of my site is domainname.com

Typing in the domain into the web gets a functional page with loaded html and css. However, when I click on a button on the site, for example, a button called "Register" which should reroute the site to a new path, though the path changes to the correct corresponding path seen in urls.py on my code, instead of generating the corresponding view, I get a 404 notfound error.
Here is what my urls.py looks like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home, name='home'),
    path("register/", views.register, name='register'),
    path("adgen/", views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('ad/create/', views.ad_create, name='ad-create'),
    path('ad/<int:pk>/', views.ad_detail, name='ad-detail'),
]
```

I have also attached what the homepage looks like which is able to generate properly:

When I enter just the domain- [www.domainname.com](http://www.domainname.com), the page generates views.home properly
However, when I enter anything past just the domain, such as [www.domainname.com/register/](http://www.domainname.com/register/), the page gives a 404 notfound error.
On views.home, I can click a button called "Register" which brings me to the path [www.domainname.com/register/](http://www.domainname.com/register/) but gives a 404 notfounderror.
I can edit urls.py (replacing "" with "hello/" in the first path), looking like the following:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("hello/", views.home, name='home'),
    path("register/", views.register, name='register'),
    path("adgen/", views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('ad/create/', views.ad_create, name='ad-create'),
    path('ad/<int:pk>/', views.ad_detail, name='ad-detail'),
]
```

and the path [www.domainname.com/hello/](http://www.domainname.com/hello/) gets a 404 notfounderror.
Moreover, if I change the view that the "" path with only the domain goes to to a different view, such as views.register, that page displays properly, such as this example:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.register, name='home'),
    path("register/", views.register, name='register'),
    path("adgen/", views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('ad/create/', views.ad_create, name='ad-create'),
    path('ad/<int:pk>/', views.ad_detail, name='ad-detail'),
]
```

This has me concluding that the program is clearly reading urls.py to generate the views that are displayed, but it also seems that the program only will display a view if the path does not contain anything beyond just the domain, which confuses me. Moroever, while I encounter this issue on my cpanel deployment of the django project, when I run this django project locally on my machine, I do not encounter this issue at all and all of my views and paths work just fine, making me conclude that this relates to the cpanel deployment of the django app. Even if anyone here does not know what to do in this specific case, I would also appreciate any advice/tips on how to approach debugging this issue!
EDIT: I was recently looking into this, but does this issue relate to .htaccess?